# How can I show time of audio/video when hover mouse on waveform?

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

I use wavesuffer and plugin cursor to show waveform of my audio/video. Now I want show time of audio/video when hover mouse on waveform, but plugin cursor don't support :(. How can I do that?

Sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

No sure I understand your need, but perhaps have a look on the click action to know how seek is defined and convert it to time ?
See : 'handleEvent' on wavesurfer.

Hope this can help you. If not tell us more information, test code ....

Comment: I did it, I used mousemove event on container of wavesuffer<br/>
`$(wavesurfer.container).mousemove(function(e) {
                var hover_time = wavesurfer.drawer.handleEvent(e, true) * wavesurfer.getDuration();
// Next step: parse hover_time from number to string and put it to one empty div.
// Next step: set position div stick with mouse postion
            }).mouseleave(function(e){
                //When mouse leave container of wavesuffer, I hide div contain hover_time
            });`